# Why won't jQuery's .text() recognize \n?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, formatting

I am trying to print html text on a page.
Right now I am doing

```
$("#generate_html_button").click(function(){
    var generated_html_text = $("#visual_form").html();
    $("#generated_html_text").text(generated_html_text);//generated_html_text is just a <div> element
  });
```

If I print the generated_html_text to the console it will come out looking like

```
<div class="dropDown form-group ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle col-xs-12" id="0" style="display: block;">
          <div>
            <label>dropdown</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control">
              <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
              <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
```

the console will use the proper forming. When I use `.text()` to print the text to my page, it ignores the `\n` and just prints it in one long line.

```
<div class="dropDown form-group ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle col-xs-12" id="0" style="display: block;"> <div> <label>dropdown</label> </div> <div class="form-group"> <select class="form-control"> <option value="option1">Option 1</option> <option value="option2">Option 2</option> </select> </div> </div>
```

Most suggest using .replace(), but when I tried `generated_html_text = generated_html_text.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');` but that will produce the same result just with 
 everywhere without the formatting, and I am trying to avoid having `<br>`s in my output. I have also tried changing `.text()` to `.html()` but then it just renders the elements. Why won't .text() recognize the existing `\n`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make whitespace significant, try the CSS `white-space: pre-wrap` on your container element.

Answer (score 0):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

```
<?php
echo nl2br("foo isn't\n bar");
?>
```

will output :

```
foo isn't<br />
bar
```